# Bootstrap Modal - modal-backdrop element is not getting generated

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Hi so I'm trying to render a bootstrap modal and everything works fine except for the fact that there is no backdrop in the modal. I checked the inspect tab and the 'modal-backdrop' element is not getting generated as far as I can see.

[image]

This is the modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade loginmodal" id="loginmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <form id="form-leads-login" name="form-leads-login" class="form-custom-select">
                        <div class="d-block mb-3">
                            <span class="form-header">
                                {vrt_login_popup_header}
                            </span>
                            <span class="cross" data-dismiss="modal">X</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-sub-header">{vrt_login_popup_welcome}</div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="popup-email" name="email" placeholder="Email ID">
                            <div class="text-error" id="text-error-popup-email"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group passwordfield">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control passwordinput" id="loginpasswordinput" name="loginpassword" placeholder="Enter password">
                            <div class="text-error" id="text-error-loginpassword"></div>
                            <img src="/ho/static/svg/bvleads/icons/freelancer/icon-eye.svg" alt="Toggle Password" class="eyecon togglepasswordicon eyeconclass">
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-process-login">
                            Login to Belvilla
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Can't figure out what the issue is here.

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt where this issue is present ?

Comment: It works perfectly. If you have any problem, please create a snippet/fiddle in order to show your issue.